# javascript: switch elements of each element in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensinal array containing a list of pairs of coordinates:

```
var coordinates = [
[
    16.383223226146004,
    48.21122334186088
],
[
    16.384753966103307,
    48.211128793925674
],
[
    16.384923422642906,
    48.211127770652936
],
[
    16.38575514277135,
    48.21122830416087
]...
```

What is the most performant option to switch the coordinate pairs around for all the entries in the array. The list of coordinates can be very long, so I'm looking for a fast working solution.

Expected result:

```
coordinates = [
[
    48.21122334186088,
    16.383223226146004
],
[
    48.211128793925674,
    16.384753966103307
],
[
    48.211127770652936
    16.384923422642906,
],
[
    48.21122830416087,
    16.38575514277135
]...
```

Comment: The most performant option probably is to change the access-methods/-indizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the most performant option to switch the coordinate pairs around for all the entries in the array!

Generally speaking the fastest is usually the simplest, regular loops and just setting the array indices

```
for (var i=coordinates.length; i--;) {
    var temp = coordinates[i][0];
    coordinates[i][0] = coordinates[i][1];
    coordinates[i][1] = temp;
}
```

Here's a JSPerf to test different methods

http://jsperf.com/switch-elements

It's about 95% faster than `forEach` and `reverse`

[image: jsperf]

That's a huge difference, while this code changes the indices in an array with 1000 arrays almost ***500k times***, the code using `forEach` and `reverse`, only executes 17k times.

Comment: You can do `[coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]] = [coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]]` to achieve the same switching effect. Not sure about the efficiency, though.

Comment: @Awesomeness01 - Yes, today destructuring is an option, Back in 2014 it wasn't.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the date, my bad. So used to it that it seems like it always was this way.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function

```
coordinates.forEach(function (coordinate) {
    coordinate.reverse();
})
```

Comment: You don't need the `coordinate = ` here as `reverse()` is in-place.